# Is there a python equivalent to perl's module-starter?

Tags: python, perl, module

Is there a python equivalent to perl's module-starter?

Comment: You might want to add a description of module-starter, or at least a link to some documentation. python experts will not necessarily know perl very well.

Comment: Can you specify what tasks you would like such a module-starter to perform, particularly in the context of python?

Comment: FYI: https://metacpan.org/module/module-starter

Comment: Python doesn't really need as much skeletal code as perl does. Maybe you just need a template for your editor?

Comment: Perl doesn't need the skeletal code either, but it's considered rather important to bundle installation and testing kit with your code.

Comment: Also, on the Perl side, [Dist::Zilla](http://p3rl.org/Dist::Zilla) can ease things by autogenerating the skeleton when needed (i.e. before a release) based on your actual code and a small ini file. TIMTOWTDI after all. (At the risk of sounding flamey, does python really not have even one way to do it?)

Comment: As the creator of Module::Starter, I officially endorse using Dist::Zilla as the heir to Module::Starter.

Answer (score 6):

You probably looking for something like [`paster create`](http://pythonpaste.org/script/) that can create the skeleton for new projects for various frameworks. Some libraries may provide custom commands to create a new project e.g.,:

```
python -m cyclone.app -p foobar
```

The literal equivalent might be [modern-package-template](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/modern-package-template) that uses `paster` to create a Python project with distribute and buildout support (I've never used it personally).

To package your application for Debian/Ubuntu you could use [`pkgme`](http://pkgme.net/doc/authors/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

I barely speak Perl and have never used module-starter, but you might want to give [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html) a look.